# Excel bill paying checklist with different currencies

Tags: excel, excel-formula, currency, billing, money-format

## Heading

so I'm starting to learn really soon abroad, there-for ill be needing to handle my own billings.
i would like to handle it in EXCEL form.
but the problem is that i have different currencies EUR,USD,HUF and ILS.

**Problem**

- adding to new lines to stock .price (currencies) so it'll keep all dates and it'll be easy to keep track
- tried doing it with macros (found out i don't really know how to)
- cant keep currencies from different date and adding "today" automatically every day

thanks for the help for who can help.

if anybody has a different way / solutions how to handle money management with different currencies (when i need total in 1 currencies) then i would like to hear your idea and learn from you. thanks

**similar to**

XE Travel Expense Calculator
https://www.xe.com/travel-expenses-calculator/

Comment: Will you get a conversion rate for that transaction at that point in time or will it be via credit card so the rate actually used will be 2 or 3 days later? I would convert to ine “master” currency and work the total from there.

Comment: i'll be using all sort of items
credit, paypal. cash, checks